# In Microsoft Teams, can I arrange the order of channels?

Tags: microsoft-teams

It looks like the alphabetical order. I tried to change it, but still does not work. Can I change their order manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can sort them manually at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't anywhere near a programming question, @rafe.

But @TonyX is right, we don't support reordering at the moment. It's mainly for performance reasons. We need to preserve sort order across devices, which means saving it somewhere, and retrieving it, adding to our application load time.

Comment: Got it. thanks for letting me know the design consideration.

Comment: Now that Teams does support manual ordering, is there a programmatic way of doing so?  It would be great if we could use PowerShell or such to manage the ordering of teams, which teams and channels are shown/hidden, managing notification preferences, etc.!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot]

My workaround is that I'm using **spaces** to arrange the order!

The name cannot start with a space, but I'm using it in combination with subgroups.

The real name of the first channel is: *APP - [space]General*.

Teams seems to truncate them, so it still looks allright! :)

You can add more spaces for more granular ordering.

Check out the status of [the user-voice item](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/20589934-sort-order-channels)